# Is it true that the Parabolid is not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have given $M=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^{3}}:z=\frac{ax^{2}}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}\right\}$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
As I understood this would be a pseudoparabolid in $\mathbb{R^3}$ dependent also on which $a$ we pick.

I need to know if this set is compact. I struggle so much with compactness of sets. I understand that a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ needs to be bounded and closed to have compactness but I have no clue about a practical way to solve this things.

I tried to see the graph in Geogebra and try to understand closeness and boundness from the graph, but am not very good at it. For $a>0$ I would assume that since the graph goes on upwards forever, it isn't bounded? so it can't be compact?
I also had to do the excercise of compactness in the case of the Cylinder and I went with the same argumentation, but don't know if it makes sense.

Also if the argumentation is true and I don't have any 3D-Plotting programm available I don't know if there is some easy and practical way to check these things out.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I saw that you already asked several questions and never accepted one. Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set is unbounded, and therefore it is not compact. And it is unbounded because, for instance, it contains every point of $\Bbb R^3$ of the form $\left(x,0,\frac{ax^2}2\right)$ and the distance of such a point to $(0,0,0)$ is greater than or equal to $|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

$M$ is certainly not compact. The sequence $\{m_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence of $M$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and

$$m_n=(2n,2n,2(a+1)n^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

For any given $a$, this is the graph $\Gamma$ of a function $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, namely $f(x,y)=\frac{ax^2}2+\frac{y^2}2$. Therefore it is unbounded becasue for all $x,y$ there is some $z$ such that $(x,y,z)\in\Gamma$.